# jQuery preventdefault on form submit goes wrong on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, preventdefault

I'm using a form submit with validation on jqtransformed items. Strange thing is that submit control only works for once. If i submit the form correct in my first try, it sends the value. But if i don't, it alerts me and never submits again.

Here is my sample work.

```
function jqkontrol(){
    var alis = jQuery("#alis_yeri div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span").text();
    var donus = jQuery("#donus_yeri div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span").text();
    if(alis!='Alış Yeri Seçiniz' && donus!='Dönüş Yeri Seçiniz'){
        jQuery("form#rezervasyon").submit();
        return true;
    }else{
        alert('Alış noktası seçiniz.');
        jQuery("form#rezervasyon").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        return false;
    };
}

<form>
<input type="image" src="http://www.guiderentacar.com/yeni/tema/bg_devamet.png" onclick="jqkontrol();" />
</form>
```

Here is the live version: [Live Demo of the Source.](http://www.mustafabugra.com/test/webhox/jqtransform2/jqtransform.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code here:

```
    jQuery("form#rezervasyon").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

establishes an event handler for the "submit" event on the form. The handler is permanent; well, it's permanent until you explicitly take it away, which you don't.  Thus, if you have errors, you set up that handler, and then from that point on you'll never be able to submit the form; that handler will always prevent the default operation.

Instead of doing that, do the following (I think):

1. Change the "onclick" handler for the submit image:

   ```
   <input type="image" src="http://www.guiderentacar.com/yeni/tema/bg_devamet.png" onclick="jqkontrol(event);" />
   ```
2. Change the validation code:

   ```
   function jqkontrol(ev){
      ev = ev || window.event; // for IE
      var alis = jQuery("#alis_yeri div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span").text();
      var donus = jQuery("#donus_yeri div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span").text();
      if(alis!='Alış Yeri Seçiniz' && donus!='Dönüş Yeri Seçiniz'){
         return true;
      }else{
         alert('Alış noktası seçiniz.');
         if (ev.preventDefault) ev.preventDefault();
         ev.returnValue = false; // for old IE
      };
   }
   ```

Comment: So: unbind the submit event to erase the preventDefault() before you submit your form.

Comment: @JNDPNT there's no point binding the event handler in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I didn't know that i bind that prevent action permanently.

Comment: @Mustafa actually I need to edit it so that it'll work in IE ... give me a sec